# Reading strings to a structure member in C++

Tags: c++

I am from C#, Java background trying to learn C++. The following is a snippet I found for reading values for a structure variable. Could not quite figure out what is being done or whether this is the standard way of reading a string structure member. Isn't there a more cleaner way to do this.

```
   string mystr;

   struct structdefn
   {
     string member;
     ...
   } mystruct[10];

   ...
   getline (cin,mystr);
   stringstream(mystr) >> mystruct[n].member;
```

Comment: Do you have any information as to how `mystr` and `mystruct` are defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code uses a temporary `stringstream` fed with a line read from stdin to read the data into the struct member. Although there are some reasons for which you may be doing that (e.g. to check that the `>>` operator consumes the whole line), generally you could more simply do

```
cin >> mystruct[n].member;
```

As for the explanation of your code:

- `getline` reads a whole line from `cin` (the standard input stream) and puts it into the `string` mystr;
- a temporary object of type `stringstream` is then created; `stringstream`s are a particular type of streams which aren't fed from a file/socket/whatever, but from a `string`. In this case, the string is `mystr`, the line just read from the standard input;
- on that temporary object is called the operator `>>`, which, in this context, is called the *extraction operator*<sup>1</sup>; it's work is to extract from the stream and convert the data that will be put in the variable on its right, in this case `mystruct[n].member`.

The simpler code I posted just uses the operator `>>` directly from the standard input stream (`cin`), thus avoiding the intermediate passage of the `stringstream`.

---

1. Although with integers it's the binary right shift operator (which it's its original meaning).

Comment: Just so the OP knows, this will work, but reading from the stream this way will only read until it encounters a whitespace character. The `getline` will read until a newline (`\n`) is found. As you said, it depends on what s/he is trying extract from the stream.

Comment: @Will: what you say about `getline` is true, but notice that it's not used to feed directly `mystruct[n].member`, but it's feeding the `stringstream`, which then uses the same `operator>>` that would be used on `cin`. A difference in the two methods from the perspective of what is put in `mystruct[n].member` should arise only if is used an `operator>>` which do not stop reading at newlines (so it would go on reading on `cin`, while on the `stringstream` it would stop at the `\n` for EOF).

Comment: I thought that `>>` would stop at a newline since it is considered whitespace? Does it treat that differently?

Comment: @Will: we don't know the type of `member`: if it's a string the normal `operator>>` will stop at whitespace, but what if it's a user-defined type with a custom `operator>>` which do not care about newlines (e.g. an operator that reads multiple scalars to load data for a structure - for it the newline may just be a delimiter)? The two snippets in general will behave differently.

Comment: that's true, I hadn't thought of it that way, though the original question (I thought) was dealing only with string data; but you are definitely right on that - what if it's an object that overrides `>>`. It would most definitely depend on the implementation details at that point.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `mystr` and `mystruct[n].member` are both `std::string` instances, I'm not sure why the `stringstream` is being used - you should be able to simply read directly into the `member` string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
// Assuming that mystruct[n].member is a std::string
std::getline ( std::cin, mystruct[n].member );
```

It would be more helpful to have the declaration of the `mystruct` structure.

**EDIT**:
You can make use of the `stringstream` if the data you are reading and storing into the structure member is not the entire line of text. The extraction operator `>>` will extract a "word" at a time from the string, where whitespace delimits the "words" in the line of text. Example:

```
// Where the line of text is "123 abc pdq" ...
std::string s;
std::getline ( std::cin, s ); // s now contains: 123 abc pdq
std::stringstream ss ( s );
ss >> mystruct[n].member; // member will contain: 123
```

There are ways to change the behavior of the stream regarding how the whitespace is handled, but this is the most commonly used way of extracting parts of a string of text into other strings.

Answer (score 1):

The std::stringstream class is useful for complex string formatting (think printf, but type-safe), and converting between strings and other types.

For example, where you would use Integer.parseInt in Java, you would use std::stringstream in C++.

```
int i;
std::stringstream("123") >> i;
```

If you don't need to do conversion, and you don't need to string formatting, then you probably don't need a stringstream.

Comment: It would also be useful if the data is whitespace-separated; s/he could use it to easily parse the line into "words".